# PHP Syntax Error with unexpected 'true' (T_STRING), expecting ')'

Tags: php, syntax-error

I get this error when using php code

> PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'true' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in your code on line 3568

please help me i dont understand whats wrong here php code line

```
static $true  = array('1xtracts'true', 'True', 'TRUExtracts'y', 'Yxtracts'yes', 'Yes', 'YESxtracts'on', 'On', 'ONxtract);
```

Comment: You're not escaping the quotes..

Comment: Your also missing a quote near the end `'ONxtract);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must escape the quotes.

```
static $true  = array('1xtracts\'true', 'True', 'TRUExtracts\'y', 'Yxtracts\'yes', 'Yes', 'YESxtracts\'on', 'On', 'ONxtract');
```